# С# WinForms. Обновить данные в форме

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Имеется 2 формы, **form1** - картинки с названиями велосипедов, форма **AddBicycle** - для добавления нового велосипеда в магазин. Проблема заключается в том, что при добавлении велосипеда он не добавляется в **form1**(**flowLayoutPanel**). На данный момент имею на **form1** кнопку для перезапуска формы, код:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    Form1 form = new Form1();
    form.Show();
}
```

После добавления велика форма **AddBicycle** закрывается:

```
this.Close();
```

При перезапуске приложения велосипед добавляется.
Желаемый результат:

Необходимо при закрытии формы **AddBicycle** на существующей форме **form1** автоматически обновлять данные. То есть из  **AddBicycle** при событии - *закрытие* получить доступ к **form1**, очистить **flowLayoutPanel**,  заново записать в него данные с новым великом.

Comment: Судя по описанию вам достаточно открывать форму `AddBicycle` как диалоговое окно. Тогда можно использовать обычное добавление свойства `Bicycle` к форме  `AddBicycle`, а при закрытии извлекаете свое транспортное средство и помещаете его в коллекцию.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена путем добавления события Focus Activated на главной форме. `

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddBicycle add_byc = new AddBicycle();
        add_byc.ShowDialog();
    }//Фокус на форме add_byc
```

При закрытии формы add_byc (возврат фокуса на form1), срабатывает событие:

```
private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Adding_Bikes_to_FLP();
        //Добавляем контролы в flowLayoutPanel
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Здесь будем исползовать метод `ShowDialog()`, и после закрытие форма `AddBicycle` вызываем метод для получения данные велосипедов заново в Form1.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Метод для получения данные велосипедов
    void GetBicycleList()
    {
        //картинки с названиями велосипедов
    }

    private void btnOpenAddBicycle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        frmAddBicycle frmbicycle = new frmAddBicycle();
        frmbicycle.ShowDialog();

        //Вызвать метод для получения данные велосипедов
        GetBicycleList();
        this.Show();
    }
}
```